# Am I taking the appropriate approach to insulate + properly ventilate my attic?

Tags: insulation, attic, ventilation, soffit

I have a question about the ventilation + insulation of my attic space, and what needs to be done to correct it. I apologize if any of my terms are incorrect, as I am certainly no engineer or carpenter, and I am in climate zone 6 - humid, cool summers and cold, dry winters.

My house is an 1830s-built 1 1/2 story cape-style gable construction with no knee-wall storage spaces. Each gable has a window that was installed, but does not allow for air movement at all and after walking around this part of the home discovered there are no soffit vents or gable vents. The roof is a metal roof, approximately 20 years old, and does have ridge-line vents (though I can't inspect the exterior of them yet).

As you can see from my pictures, there is condensation occurring in the attic space on the windows (especially the larger one, which faces the sun most of the day), and I assume this means that the ridge-ventilation alone is not enough. Soffit vents could be installed on the front side of the home, but in the rear an addition (and a later planned addition) will block the soffits from the exterior.

In this cause should I go with the soffit vents on just the front, or would gable vents over the windows be a better solution? Also, should those gable-ends walls be insulated? From what I've researched the answer is no, but would like a second opinion on it. This space is purely unfinished, though there is the possibility of building a platform and storing things up here once it's sealed up.

Thanks in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're insulating the spaces between the rafters, right?

Comment: @popham I was not planning on insulating the rafters. This space is completely unfinished, and the only area that is heated is below, so in theory only the floor should be insulated. I also think the insulation on the gable ends should be removed, right?

Comment: If the air up there is condensing on windows, my guess would be you breathing or a steamy bathroom as the humidity source. Is it normal for that window to have condensation when there's nobody doing stuff up there?

Comment: @popham I don’t believe so, though it’s hard to tell. The window was extremely dirty (seemed like dirt, but could have been a mix of dirt and mildew), but I cleaned it up yesterday. Bathroom is on the other end of the house and does not vent through this attic, so it may just be from my breath. Our house has been very humid as of late, with condensation even forming inside of the first floor windows in the morning. I’ve grabbed the dehumidifier and opened a few windows today in hopes  of clearing a bit of the humidity in the main living space.

Comment: Frequent condensation + dusty environment = extremely dirty window. The one window looks operable--there's your gable vent. My climate has low humidity summers, where everything dries out seasonally. If the high humidity is an unusual seasonal thing (which your "as of late" suggests to me), then _I_ wouldn't worry about it. You should probably amend your question with climate information.

Comment: You seem to have a ridge vent(good).  soffit vents will help, but if you need gable vents I would place near the floor.  With the ridge vent, you don't need high exhaust vents but intake vents.  The lower house humidly is probably a different cause to the attic.  Do you have vapour barrier between the floor and insulation on the attic floor?

Comment: @popham I’ve updated my original post. I am in zone 6 in the US; humid cool summers and dry cold winters. The condensation on the windows on the first floor is new to this year, but we had an extremely wet summer, and might be the route of that issue. The double hung window does open but doesn’t stay open.

Comment: @crip659 I was definitely leaning towards the gable end vents anyways, and placing them below the window does make sense now that you mention it to increase the flow up and out of the attic. from everything that I can tell, there is no vapor barrier between the interior ceiling and the cellulose blown in insulation above. This was done sometime ago, and I plan on correcting it eventually. From everything I’ve read, I shouldn’t have a vapor barrier on the fiberglass batts laid on the floorboards as an old trap moisture up against the boards.

Comment: I had a vinyl double hung window with bad springs. Once I got the bad springs free, I searched the internet for the random sequence of alphanumeric characters etched into the springs. New ones popped up on the first page: 20 USD plus shipping for the pair.